# MDriven's diagram navigation for practicality

Tags: modeling, mdriven

When building bigger databases with many classes, I like to keep my diagrams clean in the way most people do. Coloring the classes differently depending on function, squaring the AssociationLines for a more clear view, adding smaler ViewModels and StateMachines into the diagram to see what I'm working with etc.
It helps with the overall work flow and convenience.

---

Having swiched to MDriven, I am happy with the layout even if it took time to get used to. Since keeping things organized is so important for me, QuickFunctions such as 'square lines' were and are really appreciated. But how come you can not mark more than one object in a diagram at once to move them?

---

I'm not sure how big of a demand there is to make it worth changing but it would certainly be a welcome one. It's the only function I have found myself missing and don't see a problem with having it there since the other modelling tools I've used have all had it. Maybe it isn't there because MDriven isn't as big as other programs as of right now and therefore does not have the sufficient amount of feedback needed to correct these sort of things.

---

I know that the founder sees the posts tagged with 'mdriven' and hope he responds! I'm not alone when I say that this is a necessity, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see your point. Would "ctrl + a" when in a diagram satisfy your needs in the practical way? From my own experience I've found myself wanting to execute "ctrl + a" -> "square lines" without being able to do so.

Comment: @JoeAndersson Both would convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you click and drag in the white space in a diagram you get a select square - the things completely within will all be selected and can the be moved as group.

You can also hold ctrl-key while selecting to build up a set of selected things that then can be moved as a group.

Comment: I have obviously tried this, but apperently it does not work for me however? Or is this a new fix?